# Applying Kramers-Kronig relation to a simple damped oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, signal-processing, linear-systems, analyticity

I just discovered the [Kramers-Kronig relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) and am trying to apply it to a simple damped oscillator of the form subjected to an impulse at $t=0$, which is a causal system:

$$m\ddot x + c\dot x + k x = \delta(t).$$

In the time-domain, the response can be decomposed in odd/even parts as $x(t) = \operatorname{sign}(t)h_0(t) + h_0(t)$. The Kramers-Kronig relation implies that because the signal is causal, the real part of the Fourier transform of a solution $x(t)$ is equal to the Hilbert transform of the imaginary part of the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. That is what I am trying to illustrate here (and I am afraid that it would lead to a constraint between $m$, $c$ and $k$, which would probably suggest a misunderstanding on my side...).

The Fourier transform of the ODE gives
$$ (-m \omega^2 +k + ic\omega )\hat x   = 1$$

so

$$\hat x = \dfrac{1}{-m \omega^2 +k + ic\omega } = \dfrac{k-m\omega^2}{(k-m\omega^2)^2 + (c\omega )^2} + i \dfrac{-c\omega}{(k-m\omega^2)^2 + (c\omega )^2} $$

If I am not mistaken, the KK relation would imply that the Hilbert transform of $\dfrac{-c\omega}{(k-m\omega^2)^2 + (c\omega )^2} $ is  $\dfrac{k-m\omega^2}{(k-m\omega^2)^2 + (c\omega )^2}$, ie

$$\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\dfrac{1}{u-\omega}\dfrac{c\omega}{(k-m\omega^2)^2 + (c\omega )^2} d\omega \stackrel{?}{=} \dfrac{k-m u^2}{(k-m u^2)^2 + (cu )^2}$$
which does not hold (take for instance $u=m=c=k=1$, the integral [does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20w%2F((1-w%5E2)%5E2%20%2B%20w%5E2)%5E2*1%2F(1-w)%20dw%20from%20-infinity%20to%20%2Binfinity)). **Edit** Actually, it *does* hold for $m=c=k=1$, in the sense of the principal value (see hint and answer) ! I was not able to verify for arbitrary $m,c,k$.

Mathematica code for whoever is interested:

```
m = k = c = 1;
LHS  = Assuming[Element[u, Reals], 1/Pi*Integrate[-1/(u - w)*c*
      w/((k - m*w^2)^2 + (c^2*w^2)), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     PrincipalValue -> True]];
RHS = (k - m*u^2)/((k - m*u^2)^2 + c^2*u^2);
LHS == RHS // Simplify
```

Comment: Quick hint : Hilbert transform of a function $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{\pi}P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx'\frac{f(x')}{x-x'}$. Your integral certainly converges in the sense of a principal value.

Comment: @Sunyam Out of curiosity, how do you know it converges in the PV sense?

Comment: Only singularity your integral (without interpreting it in the sense of a principal value) along real axis is at $\omega=u$ which disappears when interpreted as a principal value (calculated by using semi circular contour in upper/lower plane + real axis with a dent bypassing the singular point).

Answer (score 2):

This work!

$$x=\frac{1}{-m{\omega}^{2}+k+ic\omega}=\Re{(x(\omega))}+i\,\Im{(x(\omega))}$$
with:
$$\Re{(x(\omega))}={\frac {-m{\omega}^{2}+k}{ \left( -m{\omega}^{2}+k \right) ^{2}+{c}^{2
}{\omega}^{2}}}\tag 1$$
and 
$$\Im{(x(\omega))}=-{\frac {c\omega}{ \left( -m{\omega}^{2}+k \right) ^{2}+{c}^{2}{\omega
}^{2}}} 
\tag 2$$

**Kramers-Kronig relation** :

$$I_R=-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\inf \frac{\omega\,\Im{(x(\omega))}}{\omega^2-s^2}\,d\omega$$

for $m=1\,,k=1\,,c=1$

we get:

$$I_R=\frac{1-s^2}{s^4-s^2+1}$$

this is the value of equation (1) for $\Re{(x(s))|_{m=1\,,k=1\,,c=1}}$

$$I_I=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\inf \frac{s\,\Re{(x(\omega))}}{\omega^2-s^2}\,d\omega$$

we get:

$$I_I=-\frac{s}{s^4-s^2+1}$$

this is the value of equation (2) for  $\Im{(x(s))|_{m=1\,,k=1\,,c=1}}$

to get the right answer  you must take the Cauchy-Principal -Value of the integral result :

$$I= \text{Cauchy-Principal -Value}\,\left[\int_0^\inf (...)\,d\omega\right]$$

I did the calculation with Maple symbolic program

[image]